# Difference between online and on line

Tags: word-difference

When do we use ***online*** as one word and when as two words?
For example, do we say :"I want to go ***online*** or ***on line***?"

Comment: For your sense (connected to a network / the Internet, I assume), it's always the single-word form. You might receive a phone call on line [number] one, but that's not a very common usage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the internet was more of a novelty, it seems like both forms were used. The two words were often hyphenated as well. For example, the following is a screen shot from a 1997 book entitled *The Future of Money in the Information Age*.

[image: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=getting+on+line%2C+getting+on-line%2C+getting+online&year_start=1980&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3]

And a 1992 book reads:

> Once you have a valid BBS number, it's time to dial it and get on line.

That said, it looks like the single-word form is winning out, though. It's far easier to find examples where *online* is a single word. Check out the [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=getting+on+line%2C+getting+on-line%2C+getting+online&year_start=1980&year_end=2005&corpus=15&smoothing=3).

It may be worth noting that such neologisms are not uncommon in the technology realm; here is a [similar Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=user+name+and+password%2Cusername+and+password&year_start=1980&year_end=2005&corpus=15&smoothing=3) showing how *username* is becoming a single word.

Answer (score 1):

Online = noun (place)

He searched online. - As in internet.

on = preposition,
line = noun (thing)

Generally, articles are placed in front of nouns (a, an, the)

The clothes are on THE line. 
["The line" refers to a clothes line]

She had her pens in a line.
["in" = preposition, "line" = direction]

Ms. Johnson had our class line up.
[line used as a verb]

Articles:
a - placed before a nonspecific noun
"Give me a pen.", "Where is a bathroom?" <--- Not a specific pen/bathroom

an - same as above, but if the noun begins with a vowel use "an"
"I would like an ice cream cone.", "What is an apple?"

the - placed before a specific noun
"The pen is broke.", "Where are the keys?" <---- Specific pen/keys